# customization of Drupal8 subtheme with left handside menu

Tags: customization, drupal-8, drupal-themes

I need help with changing a subtheme of drupal 8 based on a picture.
[how it have to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrgYe.png).
  this is what I have now[what I have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaXm4.png)
This is what I've done till now:
installed barrio subtheme
install "Responsive and off-canvas menu" Drupal 8 module. and followed the tutorial-> https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/responsive-offcanvas-menu/
created a form webforms
The problem is that the menu appears at the bottom of the page and the website does not look visually good. I don't know what I've done wrong and why it is not working properly.
For the subtheme, I chose Bootstrap Barrio 8.x-4.22 and I made a custom one for my project.
I need someone to help me if possible.

Comment: You can enable the twig debugging and see which template is currently loaded and modify the template according to your need. To enable Debugging mode: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the Drupal system was not able to find the mmenu-js library and that's why is performing that way. When I copy the library to the correct folder drupal/libraries it worked